# Adding a custom "page" to the Windows 7 control panel. No new application window

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, windows-7

Hello StackOverflow Community,
I hope I am able to describe my problem so that it is possible to answer it!

In abstract: I want to expand the windows 7 control panel.
I know that you can add an link to the mainpage which starts your app. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144185(v=vs.85).aspx

What I want to do the is go a step further. I you click through the control panel, you can see that there are some setting "pages" which don't open a new window. You are getting to a new "page" and in the top area is the name of the dialog added to a navigation bar.
What I want is this exact behavior for my app.

[image]
Here you see a screenshot of a settingsdialog which has the wanted behavior. I would like to integrate my app like this.

My application is going to be a settings dialog for windows 7, similar to the customization page. I already asked this question on msdn without success.

Sincerely yours,
AxP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing here is Windows itself, not some random app. It is there because Microsoft hardcoded a link to this page in a Microsoft product.

To be more precise, you see here Explorer.Exe (which contains the control panel) showing settings for the desktop background (which is also Explorer.Exe).